# Use the same image 2 times in image styles

Tags: 8, media

A tricky question regarding image styles.

I need to do a thumbnail with 2 layers:

1. background: a cropped picture with a blur effect.
2. foreground: overlay with the same picture and scale effect.

If you have some hints, or you know how to do it programmatically in a custom ImageEffect plugin I would appreciate any help.

This is an example how the image should look like:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a custom field formatter to me.

Comment: @Kevin, I think you meant custom ImageEffect plugin.

Comment: I had to implement something in the past and just did it as a field formatter. That way you can use one image, and give it options for the image style. Then when you are building it, process the image twice and then render it with a template. See https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_twentytwenty - even though this uses 1 image style, it should not be hard to adapt to that. I have never written a image style that does this... though I guess you could, technically.

Comment: A theming solution would be to build two different image style render elements for the same image, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219039/rendering-an-image-field-in-page-html-twig-with-a-custom-image-style

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the task currently without a custom image style. Only custom code:

```
/**
   * Applies an image effects blur, scale and crop.
   *
   * The result is am image with 2 layers:
   *   - background: a cropped picture with a blur effect.
   *   - foreground: overlay with the same image and scale effect.
   *
   * @param int $width
   *   Result image width.
   * @param int $height
   *   Result image height.
   * @param int $radius
   *   Result image blur radius.
   */
  public function blurScaleAndCrop($width, $height, $radius) {
    $image = $this->getImageFactory()->get($this->path);
    if (!$image->isValid()) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Image {$this->path} is not valid");
    }

    // Create the background image.
    $image->scaleAndCrop($width, $height);
    /** @var \Drupal\system\Plugin\ImageToolkit\GDToolkit $toolkit */
    $toolkit = $image->getToolkit();
    $resource = $toolkit->getResource();
    // Apply blur.
    if ($radius) {
      for ($i = 0; $i < $radius; $i++) {
        imagefilter($resource, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
      }
    }
    $image->apply('gaussian-blur', ['radius' => $radius]);

    // Create the foreground image.
    $foreground = $this->getImageFactory()->get($this->path);
    if (!$foreground->isValid()) {
      throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Image {$this->path} is not valid");
    }
    $foreground->scale($width, $height);

    // Merge the 2 image layers.
    $dst_im = $image->getToolkit()->getResource();
    $src_im = $foreground->getToolkit()->getResource();
    $f_width = $foreground->getWidth();
    $f_height = $foreground->getHeight();
    $x = ($width - $f_width) / 2;
    $y = ($height - $f_height) / 2;
    imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $x, $y, 0, 0, $f_width, $f_height);
    $image->save();
  }
```