# Render image field with custom image style in custom block template

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

This is basically the same question as this, but I can't get the technique to work in a custom block type template: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219052/71100

1. I have a custom block type called `link_card`.
2. I have an image field `field_link_card_image`.
3. I have a List(text) field to select an image style `field_link_card_size`
4. I have confirmed that `field_link_card_size` is outputting the key, which is the machine name of my image style.
5. My theme template is `block--bundle-link-card.html.twig`. It overrides `block.html.twig`. The template is working.
6. I want to render the image and use the image size selected.

Here is the **first** way I tried based on what worked in the answer for `page.html.twig`.

```
{% set image = {
  '#theme':      'image_style',
  '#style_name': content.field_link_card_image_size[0],
  '#uri':        file_url(content.field_link_card_image['#items'].entity.uri.value),
  '#alt':        content.field_link_card_image[0].alt,
 } %}

 {{ image }}
```

I get this white screen error:

> Error: Call to a member function transformDimensions() on null in
>   template_preprocess_image_style() (line 303 of
>   core/modules/image/image.module).

And this error in Report Log in the admin area:

> Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!

If I replace the value for `'#style_name:` with the just the  machine name of one of my image styles (such as `square`) it *almost kinda* works.

- The image renders but with the _incorrect image src: `/D8_1318_LinkCard/web/files/styles/square/public//D8_1318_LinkCard/web/files/2019-06/unsplash_1500x500-4.jpg?itok=c16MdkOY` (You can see it's sort of repeated itself.)
- The alt text doesn't come in at all, so I probably have that wrong, too.

This leads me to believe that **there are problems how I'm pulling in the field content from the block.**

Here is the second way I tried:

```
{% set image = content.field_link_card_image[0] %}
{% set imagestyle = content.field_link_card_image_size[0] %}|
{% set image = setimage|merge({ '#image_style': imagestyle }) %}

{{ image }}
```

The errors are:

> Error: Call to a member function transformDimensions() on null in
>   template_preprocess_image_style() (line 303 of
>   core/modules/image/image.module).
>
> and
>
> Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!
>
> and
>
> Error: Call to a member function transformDimensions() on null in template_preprocess_image_style()

This works if I do `imagestyle = 'square'`. But of course I'm trying to use the value of the field.

Here the problem seems to be an issue with getting in the field_image size to sneak into the variable `imagestyle`.

**TLDR:** How do I render an image field with a custom style in the *custom block template*.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module is exactly what I need. https://www.drupal.org/project/field_image_style

:D